# How to convert multiple lists of lists into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have extracted a table from PDF using pdfplumber and output is coming as this -

```
print(table)

Output:

[['3.42', 'EVERGY INC', 'EVRG', '30034W106', '14,208', '66.56', '713,222', '232,462'], ['3.35', 'EQUITY LIFESTYLE\nPROPERTIES INC', 'ELS', '29472R108', '6,926', '133.60', '572,177', '353,136'], ['2.94', 'RENAISSANCERE\nHOLDINGS LTD', 'RNR', 'G7496G103', '4,198', '193.45', '565,600', '246,503']]

[['1.54', 'WEYERHAEUSER CO', 'WY', '962166104', '15,396', '27.70', '458,523', '-32,054'], ['1.42', 'LAMB WESTON\nHOLDINGS INC', 'LW', '513272104', '5,407', '72.72', '347,519', '45,678'], ['1.35', 'GLOBAL PAYMENTS INC', 'GPN', '37940X102', '2,344', '159.00', '165,855', '206,841']]

[['0.91', 'CHECK POINT\nSOFTWARE\nTECHNOLOGIES LTD', 'CHKP', 'M22465104', '2,288', '109.50', '236,679', '13,857'], ['0.79', 'CARLISLE COS INC', 'CSL', '142339100', '1,501', '145.54', '151,642', '66,814'], ['0.79', 'AMETEK INC', 'AME', '031100100', '2,374', '91.82', '140,321', '77,659']]
```

Output above is 3 lists of lists. I want to combine these lists together and convert them into one pandas dataframe. Can you please help how best to iterate over table output and put them into a dataframe?
Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to convert it into dataframe.

```
In [53]: t
Out[53]:
[['3.42',
  'EVERGY INC',
  'EVRG',
  '30034W106',
  '14,208',
  '66.56',
  '713,222',
  '232,462'],
 ['3.35',
  'EQUITY LIFESTYLE\nPROPERTIES INC',
  'ELS',
  '29472R108',
  '6,926',
  '133.60',
  '572,177',
  '353,136'],
 ['2.94',
  'RENAISSANCERE\nHOLDINGS LTD',
  'RNR',
  'G7496G103',
  '4,198',
  '193.45',
  '565,600',
  '246,503'],
 ['1.54',
  'WEYERHAEUSER CO',
  'WY',
  '962166104',
  '15,396',
  '27.70',
  '458,523',
  '-32,054'],
 ['1.42',
  'LAMB WESTON\nHOLDINGS INC',
  'LW',
  '513272104',
  '5,407',
  '72.72',
  '347,519',
  '45,678'],
 ['1.35',
  'GLOBAL PAYMENTS INC',
  'GPN',
  '37940X102',
  '2,344',
  '159.00',
  '165,855',
  '206,841'],
 ['0.91',
  'CHECK POINT\nSOFTWARE\nTECHNOLOGIES LTD',
  'CHKP',
  'M22465104',
  '2,288',
  '109.50',
  '236,679',
  '13,857'],
 ['0.79',
  'CARLISLE COS INC',
  'CSL',
  '142339100',
  '1,501',
  '145.54',
  '151,642',
  '66,814'],
 ['0.79',
  'AMETEK INC',
  'AME',
  '031100100',
  '2,374',
  '91.82',
  '140,321',
  '77,659']]

In [51]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(t)

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
      0                                        1     2          3       4       5        6        7
0  3.42                               EVERGY INC  EVRG  30034W106  14,208   66.56  713,222  232,462
1  3.35         EQUITY LIFESTYLE\nPROPERTIES INC   ELS  29472R108   6,926  133.60  572,177  353,136
2  2.94              RENAISSANCERE\nHOLDINGS LTD   RNR  G7496G103   4,198  193.45  565,600  246,503
3  1.54                          WEYERHAEUSER CO    WY  962166104  15,396   27.70  458,523  -32,054
4  1.42                LAMB WESTON\nHOLDINGS INC    LW  513272104   5,407   72.72  347,519   45,678
5  1.35                      GLOBAL PAYMENTS INC   GPN  37940X102   2,344  159.00  165,855  206,841
6  0.91  CHECK POINT\nSOFTWARE\nTECHNOLOGIES LTD  CHKP  M22465104   2,288  109.50  236,679   13,857
7  0.79                         CARLISLE COS INC   CSL  142339100   1,501  145.54  151,642   66,814
8  0.79                               AMETEK INC   AME  031100100   2,374   91.82  140,321   77,659
```

**Update**:

If your list is something like this:

```
[[['3.42', 'EVERGY INC', 'EVRG', '30034W106', '14,208', '66.56', '713,222', '232,462'], ['3.35', 'EQUITY LIFESTYLE\nPROPERTIES INC', 'ELS', '29472R108', '6,926', '133.60', '572,177', '353,136'], ['2.94', 'RENAISSANCERE\nHOLDINGS LTD', 'RNR', 'G7496G103', '4,198', '193.45', '565,600', '246,503']], [['1.54', 'WEYERHAEUSER CO', 'WY', '962166104', '15,396', '27.70', '458,523', '-32,054'], ['1.42', 'LAMB WESTON\nHOLDINGS INC', 'LW', '513272104', '5,407', '72.72', '347,519', '45,678'], ['1.35', 'GLOBAL PAYMENTS INC', 'GPN', '37940X102', '2,344', '159.00', '165,855', '206,841']], [['0.91', 'CHECK POINT\nSOFTWARE\nTECHNOLOGIES LTD', 'CHKP', 'M22465104', '2,288', '109.50', '236,679', '13,857'], ['0.79', 'CARLISLE COS INC', 'CSL', '142339100', '1,501', '145.54', '151,642', '66,814'], ['0.79', 'AMETEK INC', 'AME', '031100100', '2,374', '91.82', '140,321', '77,659']]]
```

you can flatten it into list of list :

```
flatten_list = [item for sublist in new_list for item in sublist] 
print(flatten_list,sep=' ')
[['3.42', 'EVERGY INC', 'EVRG', '30034W106', '14,208', '66.56', '713,222', '232,462'], ['3.35', 'EQUITY LIFESTYLE\nPROPERTIES INC', 'ELS', '29472R108', '6,926', '133.60', '572,177', '353,136'], ['2.94', 'RENAISSANCERE\nHOLDINGS LTD', 'RNR', 'G7496G103', '4,198', '193.45', '565,600', '246,503'], ['1.54', 'WEYERHAEUSER CO', 'WY', '962166104', '15,396', '27.70', '458,523', '-32,054'], ['1.42', 'LAMB WESTON\nHOLDINGS INC', 'LW', '513272104', '5,407', '72.72', '347,519', '45,678'], ['1.35', 'GLOBAL PAYMENTS INC', 'GPN', '37940X102', '2,344', '159.00', '165,855', '206,841'], ['0.91', 'CHECK POINT\nSOFTWARE\nTECHNOLOGIES LTD', 'CHKP', 'M22465104', '2,288', '109.50', '236,679', '13,857'], ['0.79', 'CARLISLE COS INC', 'CSL', '142339100', '1,501', '145.54', '151,642', '66,814'], ['0.79', 'AMETEK INC', 'AME', '031100100', '2,374', '91.82', '140,321', '77,659']]
```

and then you can use the `pd.DataFrame.from_records` function.

**Update2**:

Other way is to combine the three dataframes into one using `pd.concat` function.

```
df_combine = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

axis=0 for concatenating along the index
ignore_index= If True, do not use the index values along the concatenation axis. The resulting axis will be labeled 0, …, n - 1

Refer the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying but that picks only first list of lists out of 3, is it possible to read all 3 lists into a single dataframe? Or how to combine all three lists of lists into one single list and then converting it into dataframe?

Comment: what's the datatype of table variable ? is it a list of list of list?

Comment: I am getting this when I --  print(type(table))   >>                                                                                          
Output:                                                                              
 <class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>

Comment: when I tried - df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table) >> print(df) showing 3 different dataframes in output, how to loop through these dataframes and join them together into one?

Comment: hopefully this should help

Comment: I have shared both the approaches to handle the issue. Either flatten the list or combine the three dataframe into one.

Comment: I think I am clear on second step on how to flatten one nested list BUT am struggling on first step to merge my lists into one single list. How to iterate through 'table' with 3 separate lists and add them into one single list?